# Api Gateway for Services

Tags: java, spring-boot, api-gateway

I am developing web services in Java. Now lets say I have 10 services and I want all my services are accessible only via Apigateway.

Now lets say I have an API Call which needs to call 4 services say A, B, C, D in order as
First A services needs to be call, then using the o/p
B and C can be called in parallel
then finally using the o/p of B & C call the Services D.

Then combine the o/p and return the response.

Now this series and parallel combination can be anything.
Is there any open source implementation which does this. I mean i provide the scenario and it automatically sends the requests or do I have to develop this gateway?

Answer (score 1):

This ...

> First A services needs to be call, then using the o/p B and C can be called in parallel then finally using the o/p of B & C call the Services D.

... sounds like an enterprise integration pattern. Both [Spring Integration](https://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/) and [Camel](https://camel.apache.org/enterprise-integration-patterns.html) provide support for composing/orchestrating service calls.

In your example, the calls could be composed into a 'message flow' (defined in XML or in these libraries' internal DSLs) and this message flow could use the libraries' built-in support for routing calls, multi casting calls, aggregating responses etc. Routing `A` to `B`, `C` might use multi casting, using the outputs from `B` and `C` to invoke `D` might use aggregation and routing.

In addition, these libraries support:

- Both in-process and remote invocations
- Non functionals such as correlation identifiers, throttlers, delayers etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are two popular projects could be used in your case:

1. camel:
   By defining XML rules, you can create flows between services or even beans. I used Camel for similar tasks.
2. zuul: This is like a router, you can redirect requests to other services immediately or write some logic to control the flow.

Comment: zuul i dont think cant be used? as I cant aggregate multiple requests? its just route? So how can i aggregate requests using zuul? like the scenario I have mentioned in my question

Comment: yes, zuul is just a router, I used it along with camel in a api gatway project. sometimes in a gateway, you only want to redirect requests to other services.